# Displaying the size of a file in CListCtrl

Tags: integer, tostring, clistctrl

I am working in Windows MFC application..In my design am displaying the file details (type,name,size) in a `CListCtrl` control. I found those file details using `FileStatus` but when I try to display, I am not able to display the file size since its an integer. I tried `CListCtrl::SetItemText` and I also tried to type cast but its not working.

```
int nIndex = m_ListCtrl.InsertItem(0, filename);
m_myList.SetItemText(nIndex, 0, fileSize);
```

m_myList is the CListCtrl variable. Can any one help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the integer to a string before you call `SetItemText`, also use sub item 1 if you want to add it to the second column.

```
CString strFileSize;
strFileSize.Format("%u", (unsigned)fileSize);

int nIndex = m_ListCtrl.InsertItem(0, filename);
m_myList.SetItemText(nIndex, 1, strFileSize);
```